# Is it possible to have a button next to a search input with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

All the form examples in the docs for jQuery mobile show each form element on its own line. I would like to have a standard button (which will link to another page), to the right of a search input field.  Is that possible with jQuery Mobile?

Thanks

Comment: I believe a better solution to what you are wanting is also asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14129304/469643). I found your question in my search for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively as an inline unit.  However, form elements can be used together with the layout grid system reasonably effectively:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-grids.html

Answer (score 0):

jQM's UI grids force columns of equal width. In my case, i wanted the submit button to be just the icon to allow the search box more room. i saw `<table>` mentioned in a couple posts, but discovered that other inputs (notably `selectmenu`) don't work correctly when they're children of unexpected elements. [1]

So to avoid breakage of the widgets, i managed this:

```
.ui-grid-a.my-grid-a .ui-block-a.my-block-8515-a {
    width: 84.95%;
}
.ui-grid-a.my-grid-a .ui-block-b.my-block-8515-b {
    width: 14.95%;
}
```

It's not bullet-proof, but it can be expanded to additional grid definitions. It uses specificity to get all the grid rules of the existing UI, but then redefine the column widths. No inline styles, no additional tags, and the widgets don't break. And because of specificity, it can be loaded before *or* after jQM's structure stylesheet.

[1]: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6077 jQM Github bug report

Answer (score 0):

With new version you can:
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/demos/controlgroup/#Textinputs

The old style solution still works:overwriting the ui-input-search

```
div.ui-input-search{ 
  width: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

don't forget to add *ui-btn-inline* in the class of the a href (if you use the Button markup syntax)