# Jquery mobile search box with button in fieldset full width

Tags: jquery-mobile, fieldset

I have searched a lot for placing a search button on the right side of an search field. It was very dificult to find some good solution without so many hacks.

The only one good solution I have seen is in one fieldset with 2 columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/nXHNg/1/

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="search" id="searchField" data-inline="true" placeholder="Search"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input id="btnUpdateWhat" type="button" data-inline="true" value="OK" data-mini="true"></div>       
</fieldset>
```

The problem here is the not full width of the filedset. At this moment it is not full width to 100% like the element below in the listview. Is it possible to handle this issue elegant without hacks to work on all browsers? I mean when I open it with Ipad, then it should fill the whole width of the screen to 100%.

If you have other suggestions to place a button on the right side of a search field, then place it please.

Comment: I believe what you are wanting is also asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14129304/469643). I found your question in my search for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for you.

Take a look at [this](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/) JQM plugin.

I prefer direct css change, unfortunately that is not a valid option in complex JQM mobile app.

Comment: I have tested it: http://jsfiddle.net/nXHNg/3/ but on desctop full width, the button is not coming to the full 100% like the element below. Do I am making something false?

Comment: No Niko you are not doing anything wrong. Now you need to do some css hacks. Add a id attribute to div with class grid_1. Use this to navigate to first child div and on its class .ui-btn add margin-top css and wind what value will bring it in line with search box.

Comment: You can also play with position relative and float right to force button on the right side of grid. But as you can see this grid system is much better the original one.

Comment: Hmm yes it is looking better, but when I am testing it on phone it is looking weak. If the search has 11 columns and the button 1 column, it works on landscape, but it looks bad on portrait. If its 10:2 then it looks good on portrait and not on landscape.

Comment: But really is it not possible, to positioning a search box and button to full width? This is not possible.

Comment: Without css customization it is not possible. 960 grid is currently best option. Regarding your orientation problem, on orientation change event replace grid size classes. What wrapper are you using for iPhone app?